# Runtime Annotation to validate a static variable

Tags: android, annotations

I want to create a custom annotation which when used on a method, will check if a certain static variable is valid. If not will throw an exception.

**e.g:**

```
@IDCheck
public void someMethod() {
    //code...
}
```

Which checks for an ID, stored as a global variable. It should not be null and the value must comply with some rules.
Since this ID keeps changing at runtime, I want to validate it using an annotation at runtime.

**What I tried:**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

/**
 * Checks for a valid ID.
 * <p>
 * This is a marker annotation and it has no specific attributes.
 */
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface IDCheck {
}
```

I am not sure how I can do a validation at runtime whenever a method with @IDCheck annotation is invoked.

Tried something like this:

```
import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("IDCheck")
public class IDCheckProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> arg0,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        if(!Util.isIDValid()){
            //Throw an exception.
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported();
    }
}
```

But that code in the `process` method never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check this at runtime, it is not necessary to use an annotation processor.

I recommend you use a proxy and a little reflection to make it happen. You have already defined your annotation. What you need to do is create an interface for the component you want to check and annotate the method declaration there.

```
public interface MyInterface {

    @IDCheck
    void someMethod();    

}
```

Then you use Java's dynamic proxy to create a proxy of the interface:

```
MyInterface  instance = Proxy.newProxyInstance(MyInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[]{MyInterface}, handler);
```

The third parameter is the important thing here - this is an InvocationHandler. It will get notified each time a method from the proxy has been called. You should override it's invoke() method and implement your validation there. Something like this:

```
@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(IDCheck.class)) {
        //proceed with navigation and throw exception if invalid
    }

    // delegate the method execution to a wrapped implementor of the MyInterface
}
```

This is guaranteed to work at runtime. The performance impact is not very big and it is unlikely it is even noticeable.

Comment: I don't know about the performance impact(but looks like it will have a significant impact). Also, I am not sure how many such `someMethod`s might get added in future. In which case I need to add those methods to the interface as well. Plus if we are using annotation, we can just disable it in the release build by just changing the Retention.

Comment: The performance impact is not a deal braker. If you want to stick to the annotation processor, bear in mind that it is executed at compile time, not runtime. You should think about using it to generate the validation code and adding it to the method. This way it will get executed at runtime.